# Solve a puzzle & move on to the next one

Tags: netlogo

This code is adapted directly from the `Move Towards Target Example` in the `NetLogo Models Library`, but I cannot get my agents to solve a puzzle and move on.

Puzzles are patches (rather than turtles in the `Move Towards Target Example`) with a difficulty level between 1 and 5, and agents have individual probabilities of solving puzzles based on agent attributes and the difficulty of the puzzle. I would like the patch to turn from yellow to black to illustrate when it has been solved.

This error may stem from a confusion between turtle- and patch-contexts, but if so, I'm unable to correct it. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

```
set target-puzzle min-one-of patches with [ pcolor = yellow ] [ distance myself ]  
face target-puzzle  

    to go 
    if not any? patches with [pcolor = yellow] [
        stop
      ]

    ask people [
          if distance target-puzzle = 0
          [ solve-puzzle
            set target-puzzle min-one-of patches with [ pcolor = yellow ] [ distance myself ]
            face target-puzzle ]
        ;; Once the distance is less than 1, use 'move-to' to land exactly on the target.
          ifelse distance target-puzzle < 1
          [ move-to target-puzzle ]
          [ fd 1 ]
       ]

    tick

    end

    to solve-puzzle
          ask patch-here [  
            set progress [psolve] of myself
            set difficulty difficulty - progress  
          if difficulty <= 0
           [ set pcolor black ]
        ]
    end
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or incorrect behavior, or what? If an error message, what does it say? If incorrect behavior, what is it?